# Capture a name in C macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

The following iterator macro is given to me (cannot change)

```
#define ITERATE(MACRO) \
    MACRO(v1) \
    MACRO(v2) \
    MACRO(v3) \
    MACRO(v4)
```

The idea behind this is that I can now define my own one-argument macro and pass it into the iterator to expand for `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `v4`. For example:

```
#define MYSTUFF(X) doSth(X);
ITERATE(MYSTUFF)
```

will expand to

```
doSth(v1); doSth(v2); doSth(v3); doSth(v4);
```

---

My current problem is that I want to invoke `ITERATE` within another macro which would like to pass an extra argument into `MYSTUFF` beyond one provided by the `ITERATE`.

To achieve that I was hoping that I could capture the extra parameter name with the following construct:

```
#define PARTIAL(T) FULL(UUU,T)
#define FULL(U,V) doSth(U,V)
#define START(UUU) ITERATE(PARTIAL)
START(bla)
```

I was hoping that when `ITERATE(PARTIAL)` is expanded to:

```
FULL(UUU,v1) FULL(UUU,v2) FULL(UUU,v3) FULL(UUU,v4)
```

I will actually capture the `UUU` parameter of `START` and it will be replaced by `bla`. Unfortunately that is not the case (at least in gcc).

- Do you know if such name capturing can be achieved differently?
- Or perhaps you have a different idea how to solve the problem of passing extra parameter into `MACRO`?
- I may be permitted to change `ITERATOR` definition itself but only if it doesn't break any existing code already using it.

Comment: if you're not allowed to change the macro, are you at least allowed to replace it by non-macro code?

Comment: Of course I can simply *not* use `ITERATE`, or make one on my own that would accept more arguments - if that is what you ask. I would prefer however to avoid that.

Comment: I'm suggesting to get rid of the use of macros at all, not to write another one

Comment: This sounds like a job for compiled code.

Comment: I am using the iterator macro to define enums, debug enum values, having a series of functions for each enum value etc. Coding without macros requires that one has to explicitly edit each such use case when the base list (`v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `v4` in the example) is changed. It is possible, but you really don't want to do that! I didn't mention all this in the question for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it this way. Your `START()` macro basically takes a single argument, which it then discards.

What you can do is define `UUU` where you need it, eg.

```
#define PARTIAL(T) FULL(UUU,T)
#define FULL(U,V) doSth(U,V)
#define START() ITERATE(PARTIAL)

// ...

#define UUU blah

START()

#undef UUU
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, simplified, looks like this:

```
#define FOO UUU
#define START(UUU) FOO
START(5)
```

Here's what happens:

- macro `START` is encountered in line `START(5)`

  - START is a function-like macro, so it becomes expanded with argument `UUU`=5):

    - **stage 1 (argument expansion):** macro arguments are macro-expanded
      Nothing happens, `5` is not a macro.
      Body: `FOO`
    - **stage 2 ([argument prescan](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan)):** macro arguments are substituted into the macro body.
      Nothing happens, `UUU` is not in the body.
      Body: `FOO`
    - **stage 3 (expansion):** the body is macro-expanded again
      `FOO` gets expanded into `UUU`, which is not a macro.
      Body: `UUU`

I can't think of any clever way to expand `FOO` inside the body before the argument prescan happens. I don't think it's possible to do what you want directly.

Go with @**Hasturkun**'s workaround and make `UUU` a macro, not a parameter.